# DIV height based on child image height adds few extra pixels at the bottom

Tags: html, css

Why does the parent div of the image have a few extra pixels at the bottom. How can I remove the pixels without hard code the parent div height.

http://jsfiddle.net/6x8Dm/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.column {
    width:100%;
    background:#cc0000;
}

img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That space actually is a result of descender elements in fonts. You can get rid of it in a number of ways:

- add a `vertical-align:top` rule to the image **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yKjJe/)**
- add `font-size:0;` to the containing div **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Bmzfh/)**
- add `display:block;` to the image **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6x8Dm/1/)**

Comment: @JoshC Really interesting answer. I guess this margin is there because of the alt text in case the image is missing. Do you have any idea about the reason behind this extra pixels? The reason?

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu - no, the gap (not a margin) is there because by default images are like inline elements and the space is reserved for descender elements (e.g. g, y, j).

Comment: Thank you so much ! These 4 pixels in extra height were breaking my code.

Comment: I was in a similar boat but with many intervening divs between the image and where the extra space showed up.  Bootstrap puts `display: block` on .img-responsive already, but 4 levels or so up, there was a `display: inline-flex` div under a `display: block` div, and sure enough that's where the gap was.  Adding `vertical-align: top` to my inlined div did the trick!

Comment: FYI for the confused, descender elements are letters with tails, not _descendant_ HTML elements (hence why 'g' 'y' 'j' are examples.)  See [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17905828/3499424) (which I think is technically a duplicate Q)

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Very interesting answer that I didn't expect.

Answer (score 7):

One way is by setting `display:block` on the `img`, causing it to fill the parent.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6x8Dm/2/) - it works.

```
img {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't like that approach, you can also change the vertical alignment, as the default is `baseline`.

Comment: Hm... cool! That is correct! Do you have any idea why is that margin there?

Comment: I imagine the guys when they created the image tag. They where like... "We should add a few extra pixels under this image if it's wrapped into a div and no display property or float is added - it will be creepy :)) muahaha"