# td containing input type="submit" becomes taller than the input, amount is different between browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell containing an input:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" class="submitbutton" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
</body>
```

That input is styled to have a height of 20 pixels:

```
table
{
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td
{
  padding: 0;
}

.submitbutton
{
  width: 19px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VhhPf/2/

When I use firefox and look in the layout tab, I can see that the input is having height 20, but the td is for some reason having the height 21. In chrome, the td will get the height 24.

Why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an inline element, therefore it is being aligned to the baseline of your text.

Add `vertical-align:bottom`.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905827/why-does-my-image-have-space-underneath).