# How come child div causes vertical scrollbar to show up with absolute parent?

Tags: html, css

I have box div that takes up all space by absolute positioning.
Inside of box, there is another div which should take up same position height/width 100%.

Somehow on IE11, vertical scrollbar is showing up. (Chrome, Firefox does not show the scrollbar)

I believe scrollbar shows up because something is overflowing but I cannot figure out why.

box div's overflow has to be set to auto so if anytthing overflows it should show the vertical scrollbar but in the fiddle sample, there should not be anything that overflows as far as I understand.
Any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/30w11ph2/8/

HTML:

```
<div class='box'>
    <div class='view'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}

.view
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: will `overflow: scroll;` do the trick?

Comment: Nope cuz it would show the scroll always. My goal was not to show when there is no overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline-block elements participate in an inline formatting context. That means that there are line boxes and the inline boxes are vertically aligned inside those.

That vertical alignment can be set with `vertical-align`, which initially is `baseline`. That causes the [usually unwanted space underneath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17905827/1529630). That can be fixed setting `vertical-align` to `top`, `bottom`, `middle`, ...

In this case, my guess is that IE don't like `vertical-align: top`, so it doesn't solve this space issue underneath your element. Thus, `100% + space > 100%`, so there is overflow.

But you can solve it with

```css
.view {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
.view {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='view'></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use a block instead of an inline-block:

```css
.view {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
.view {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='view'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Oriol! I was stuck on this for whole day. Verified on my real environment that your solution works as well.