# auto-generated margins display inline

Tags: css, margin, inline

I have the following problem: I want to have three images in the same line, without margins in between. The problem is that when using *display:inline* or *display:inline-block* vertical and horizontal white spaces are generated between the images.

```
div img{
    width: 33.3333%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see the problem [in the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vd51x0yp/1/).

I know that with float:left I can solve the problem, but I would like to avoid this, because I don't like to use this unless is very necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: This is due to there being whitespace between your `<img />` tags, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/65971

Comment: For compatibility purposes, though, I'd say you'd be better off using float. Why don't you like using it? As long as you clear the floated items it shouldn't make any difference to your overall page flow.

Comment: The horizontal space is explained in [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630), and the vertical one in [Why does my image have space underneath?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17905827/1529630).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use float: left, You can clear out the space between the image tag by using HTML comment block.

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/vd51x0yp/3/)

CSS :

```
div img {
  width: 33.3333%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div>
  <img src="http://imagenesdereligion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/imagenes-de-santa-claus-santa_cla.jpg"><!--
  --><img src="http://www.conhijos.es/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/RatonPerez.jpg"><!--
  --><img src="http://hazteconellos.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/reyesmagos-1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! And for the margin below I used vertical-align:bottom. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using Flexbox**

You can set the parent div to have flexible layout using `display: flex`. It removes the white-space as well.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
div img {
  width: 33.3333%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://imagenesdereligion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/imagenes-de-santa-claus-santa_cla.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.conhijos.es/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/RatonPerez.jpg" />
  <img src="http://hazteconellos.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/reyesmagos-1.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Solution using `margin-right`**

```css
div img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -0.33em;
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://imagenesdereligion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/imagenes-de-santa-claus-santa_cla.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.conhijos.es/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/RatonPerez.jpg" />
  <img src="http://hazteconellos.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/reyesmagos-1.jpg" />
</div>
```