# Why position:absolute adds 4px to the height of the outer container and how to remove it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some kind of fluid header or whatever. The problem is that I noticed that when I add `position:absolute` to `a` elements, it adds 4 pixels to the header:
[image]

And if I remove `position:absolute`, then it doesn't add 4 additional pixels to the height:
[image]

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
<div class="content-container">
        <a href="#" class="header-logo"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/bn2vAjo.png" alt="" title=""></a>
        <nav class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Journal</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
```

```
.content-container {
    background: #292929;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-logo {
    align-self: center;
}

nav.main-menu {
    align-self: center;
}
nav.main-menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 132px;
    height: 132px;
    font-weight:600;
    position: relative;
}

nav.main-menu li a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

* {
    border: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yafs3yoo/

I am obviously missing something here but I can't figure it out myself.
I want this header to be exactly 132 pixels high (with borders), logo to be on the left side (centered vertically) and menu to be on the right side (centered vertically). How to get rid of these additional 4 pixels in the header?

Comment: There is no reason to make the `li` or links as `position:absolute`...I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by doing that.

Comment: Further, `position: absolute` wouldn't add 4px.  It just changes where things are positioned _relative to the nearest ancestor with position relative_

Comment: you are not `absolute`-ing your `li` but your `a`.

Comment: maybe `white-spaces`

Comment: It's the old `inline-block` "extra space at the bottom issue" I suspect.

Comment: Since you are using flexbox...why not keep doing it? - https://jsfiddle.net/23zoLfwt/

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, thanks, it's not li but a elements that are absolute. But I still have no idea how to fix these 4 additional pixels. I'll continue looking for that "extra space at the bottom issue".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905827/why-does-my-image-have-space-underneath

Comment: Ok, so I added vertical-align:bottom; for li elements and it fixed it.
I still don't understand why it adds 4 additional pixels to the height of ul element(or paddings of ul element or margin of li element or I don't know) when li element has relative positioning and a element is positioned absolutely inside that element.

Doesn't make any sense to me. Thanks a lot @Paulie_D. I'll use flexbox solution you provided instead of absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paulie_D hinted in the comments, just add `vertical-align: top;` to the rule for `nav.main-menu li`

https://jsfiddle.net/3z0vefLL/1/

that's due to the default vertical alignment of inline-blocks along the baseline.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't matter if you set vertical-align:top; or vertical-align: bottom;. In both cases there are no additional 4 pixels below the li elements, which doesn't make any sense to me. Default value is baseline, so when you change vertical-align from bottom to top, then it should add full text line to the height of the ul element, judging by the fact that it adds 4 pixels when you use baseline, right?

Is there any article or something which would illustrate why it happens to inline-block elements? Is that a bug?

Comment: There is some whitespace below inline and inline-block elements (by default also images)  since they are aligned at the baseline, which means there is some reserved space below them for descenders of letters like j, g p etc. which extend below the baseline. (consider that inline elements often contain text) Aligning them to the bottom or top (instead of the default baseline-alignment) avoids this.