# White line at the bottom of the page, padding related?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this site which I can't seem to figure out:

[Link to site here](https://mikaelfend17.github.io/HTMLCSS/Examination1/SPA/)

Somehow I get a white border at the bottom of the page.
When looking around people said it could be the padding so I added everywhere:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

and the only place it worked was making my width 100% Height is still more than 100%

I also tried but with no luck.

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```

Comment: If you're referring to the white at the very bottom, it's because your `<footer>` is set to `display:inline-block`. Try adding `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: Amazing how people here are worse than reddit, downvoting everything. Instead of giving me feedback, I've tried googling, checked all threads here and given everything needed in this post.

Comment: Your section-home height is set to 100vh, remove that and position the footer to absolute at the bottom. 100vh refers that the section home will take the fullheight of the viewport and any other content will be pushed further down below thus it goes down further.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I'm going with the vertical-align solution for now seems to work like I want to.

Comment: @indiehjaerta look try to remove [display:inline-block] from footer style and add overflow:hidden; this should work

Comment: @indiehjaerta I'm sorry if it seems like people just "downvote everything". There is a rationale and it might be worth investigating the community guidelines. Consider that people will not be able to reproduce your issue without visiting your site. When your site changes, the question becomes confusing and essentially useless. So you may want to consider adding your code here to avoid that obsolescence and to keep your post useful into the future. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Regarding your question, you might find this informative: [Why does my image have space underneath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905827/why-does-my-image-have-space-underneath)

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, @Highdef I just started 1 month ago and I somewhat want every section to be 100% height on my SinglePage so I don't get 2 sections visible at the same time, this was the quickest solution I found to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `footer` element has `display: inline-block`. Add `vertical-align: top` to its CSS, this will remove that white space. (Otherwise it's aligned to the baseline by default, which creates some white space below that baseline)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still have this problem you can check if last div of page/bottom of page have "p"
All you need to do is p{margin:0;}