# Strange padding on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

The grey border shouldn't be visible, it should be covered by the black border and I don't understand why it won't... here's the **CSS** code:

```
#portrait{
  width:120px;
  height:100px;
  top:20px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#prof_picture{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border: none;
}
```

**HTML** (inside a table):

```
<td id="portrait">
    <img id="prof_picture"></img>
</td>
```

and **javascript**

```
$("#prof_picture").attr('src',"profile/loading.gif");
```

I had to make the DOM inherit part of the attributes because when using that javascript line the image would assume its natural width and height and I wanted it just to fit the portrait. When I did this, the strange border appeared. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you post the full source code in a fiddle? Did you check the cellpadding, cellspacing and border attributes on the table?

Comment: Care to flesh out this jsfiddle I started for you? http://jsfiddle.net/CyV7j/

Comment: Updated @dylan JSFiddle to include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/CyV7j/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is this container div taller than required to wrap the image it contains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522047/why-is-this-container-div-taller-than-required-to-wrap-the-image-it-contains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `line-height: 0;`, `font-size: 0;` or `display: inline;` on `#profile` Fixes it in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CyV7j/6/

There is 4px of extra space added around the img element because of the way inline elements (line an `img`) are rendered inside of a table row.

Please consider styling with classes instead of ids. And restricting the use of tables to tabular data and not for the layout of photos.

Answer (score 1):

Add `font-size: 0;` to #portrait{}

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your image to become a block element:

```
#prof_picture { display:block; }
```

Alternatively you could set it to align to the bottom (will work only if its an inline (or inline-block) element), although i think there may be cases or environments where this could produce unwanted results.

```
#prof_picture { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

Images are, by default (unless specified otherwise), inline elements. Most browsers will reserve some extra space here, but you could also counter this by setting the parent's `line-height` to zero.

```
#portrait{
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get rid of the border: none; by #prof_picture. You can also try to write the border on #portrait li this

```
 border: 1px solid black;
```

As it is the right way to write a border.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using certain browsers.... you need to set this in the css:

```
img{
    outline:none;
}
```