# html/css image overlap eachother

Tags: html, css

i got one row working with four image but i wanted another row but it overlapp each other like this
[image]

this is what i want to achieve

[image]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="main_image"></div>
<div class="image123">
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="bottom" src="Image/test_image_slot.jpg"/>
        <img class="top" src="Image/light_bokeh_edit.jpg"/>
        <p>This is image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="bottom" src="Image/test_image_slot.jpg"/>
        <img class="top" src="Image/dancing.jpg"/>
        <p>This is image 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="bottom" src="Image/test_image_slot.jpg"/>
        <img class="top" src="Image/applecloud.jpg"/>
        <p>This is image 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="bottom" src="Image/test_image_slot.jpg"/>
        <img class="top" src="Image/chair.jpg">
        <p>This is image 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="image123">
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="bottom" src="Image/test_image_slot.jpg"/>
        <img class="top" src="Image/light_bokeh_edit.jpg"/>
        <p>This is image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="bottom" src="Image/test_image_slot.jpg"/>
        <img class="top" src="Image/dancing.jpg"/>
        <p>This is image 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="bottom" src="Image/test_image_slot.jpg"/>
        <img class="top" src="Image/applecloud.jpg"/>
        <p>This is image 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="bottom" src="Image/test_image_slot.jpg"/>
        <img class="top" src="Image/chair.jpg">
        <p>This is image 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

main.css

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #360836;
    text-align:center;
}

li {
    display:inline;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #d14977;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}

li a:hover {
    color: white;
}

div.main_image { 
content:url(../Image/everest.jpg);
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}

.imgContainer{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;

}

.imgContainer img{
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.imgContainer img.top:hover {
      opacity:0;
}
```

how can i make two rows or even more than two rows of image that stacks not overlap each other. I want to achieve this just using css and html and I dont want to use javascript or jquery. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean, "stacks"? different z-indexes? that'd qualify as "overlap"...

Comment: like one row with 4 img and another row with another 4 img without overlapping

Comment: what rules are applied to `.image123`? if that floats divs, then get rid of the float, or put a break/clear:both in between the two rows.

Comment: i haven't applied any rules to .image123 in css. i will try to break/clear see if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here actually isn't due to the `float` on your `.imgContainer`, though the symptoms may be misleading at first.

The behaviour you're seeing is actually because you placed `position:absolute` on all of your `.imgContainer img` elements, which means they are taken out of the flow of the document and don't affect the height of their parents at all. (The reason why the containers aren't down to 0 height is because the `<p>` within each `.imgContainer` still takes space.) As a result, the images overlap each other because their parents are shorter than them.

What I would suggest is only applying `position:absolute` to the image that appears on top (rather than both top and bottom), and also applying `position:absolute` to the `<p>` so it can be positioned over top of the images (and won't end up between the image rows after the images are properly positioned).

So the CSS declaration blocks I would add/rewrite are:

```css
.imgContainer img{
    /* position:absolute removed */
    display:block
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.imgContainer img.top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.imgContainer p {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;

    /* So the element doesn't block hover event of image */
    pointer-events: none;

    /* Vertical centering */
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t1wucqq/4/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** Vertical spacing between image rows was removed by applying `display:block` to the child images. Sourced from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522047/why-is-this-container-div-taller-than-required-to-wrap-the-image-it-contains).

Comment: wow!! it works. There is only one problem, there is a tiny gap between two rows. apart for that it works!!! thanks

Comment: @WESTKINz Oh! Good point on that gap - let me see if I can fix that.

Comment: @MichaelBarreiro Heh, guess it's just a case of great minds thinking alike. =P

Comment: @WESTKINz By the way, I've edited my answer to address the problem you brought up. Let me know if that's good enough for your purposes!

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly sure why your code is giving you that result, it might have something to do with giving your images a position of absolute. But I made a little snippet below that does what you want. Instead of using the img tags I just created a div that acts like the images container and gave that div a background image of the image. I find it always makes the code more simple. When you view the code, view it in full page so you can see it more clearly.

Hope this helps!

```css
.imgContainer{
  width:100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }
.imgBOX{
  height:350px;
  width:350px;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/black-and-white-wallpaper-5.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
 }
.imgBOX2{
  height:350px;
  width:350px;
  background-image: url(https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/black-white-background-32.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class='imgContainer'>
  <div class='imgBOX'></div>
  <div class='imgBOX'></div>
  <div class='imgBOX'></div>
  <div class='imgBOX'></div>
</div>
<div class='imgContainer'>
  <div class='imgBOX2'></div>
  <div class='imgBOX2'></div>
  <div class='imgBOX2'></div>
  <div class='imgBOX2'></div>
</div>
```